# newcommand says missing number

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, optional-arguments, arguments

I plan to write a command which rounds a number with n digits. n is an optional argument and it is 2 by default. However, I keep receiving error message:

> Missing number, treated as zero. Let's see if this prints: \round{3.1415926,2}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\round}[2][2]{\pgfmathparse{round({#1}*10^{#2})/(10^{#2})}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
Let's see if this prints: \round{3.1415926,2}.
\end{document}
```

What have I done wrong? How to fix this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the issue with the additional comma, I think that you got the order of `#1` and `#2` wrong, and there are already means that do precisely what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\round}[2][2]{
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,std,precision=#1}
\pgfmathprintnumber{#2}
}

\begin{document}
Let's see if this prints: \round{3.14159262}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to change the decimal separator using a comma?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am passing the result of another expression to `\round`. It seems latex send the raw command to it rather than the result of the expression causing error. Is there any way to get around this problem?

Comment: @pzorba75 There is the option `/pgf/number format/read comma as period=true|false`, see section 92 of the pgfmanual.

Comment: I follow it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/433144/).

Comment: @marmot, Thanks. I just leave it there in case anyone would like to follow the next question.